# My Site Settings: Language Options not applied

Tags: 2013, my-site, central-administration, language

On a SharePoint 2013 Server CA
Services Applications > User Profile Service > Setup My Sites:

> The Language Options check box: **Allow user to choose the language of their personal site**

**Checking in** the above option doesn't result in any prompt for the user to select the desired language (as occurs on SP2010 version) on the My Site creation.

Ideas?

Comment: SP13 release MS assumed issue.